# Pass arguments to websocket in Django

Tags: javascript, python, django, websocket

When working with websockets, how do I pass arguments to the server side from the browser?
I want to return Hello,  from the server when the browser makes a WS request. The  shall be passed from the client.

JavaScript run in the browser.

```
var socket = new WebSocket('ws://<IP>:80/ws/hello/');
        socket.onmessage = function(event){
        var data = JSON.parse(event.data);
         console.log(data);
}
```

The routing.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .consumers import *

ws_urlpatterns = [
    path('ws/hello/', Hello.as_asgi())
]
```

The consumers.py

```
from channels.generic.websocket import WebsocketConsumer
class Hello(WebsocketConsumer):
    def connect(self):
        self.accept()
        self.send(json.dumps({'message':"Hello, <NAME>!"}))
```

How do I get the NAME to be replaced with the client's name?

Can I in the JavaScript code use

```
var socket = new WebSocket('ws://<IP>:80/ws/hello/?<NAME>');
```

When I do that, how do I pass the name to the Hello class in consumers.py and shall I add something special in routing.py?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send data to a websocket server, you want to use `socket.send('string to send')`

See : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications#sending_data_to_the_server

No need to edit the websocket connection URI.

To change NAME just make that section of string a python variable, and change that variable's value to whatever you want.